# Trying to disable users who are inactive in A.D for over X time

Tags: batch-file, active-directory

I've written a script that searches in specific OU's users who are inactive for over 13 weeks (which is roughly 90 days) and disable them without moving them to a different OU (intentionally) and then it writes those users to a txt file

This script gets the job done but in a crooked manner:

```
@echo off

echo [%date%,%time%] >>c:\DisabledLogs\disabledusers.txt

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dsquery user "OU=Users,OU=Bla,DC=Bla,DC=co,DC=il" -inactive 13') 
do ( dsmod user %%a -disabled yes)>>c:\DisabledLogs\disabledusers.txt
```

It creates a TXT file with the time stamp, then searches the OU for inactive users and in the DO portion disable them using dsmod...

The downside however is that for each time that the script scans the inactive users *it writes* them down in the TXT before disabling them...

**The major issue here is that if we assume that on Sunday the script found 5 users and wrote it down to a TXT file, And on Monday it found 2 users - On the log file for Monday it will show 7 users instead of only 2... And so on and so on!**

I am trying to break this script into three loops:

```
For for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dsquery user "OU=Users,OU=Bla,DC=Bla,DC=co,DC=il" -inactive 13') do set”b=%%a”

For /f “delims=” %%x in (dsquery * -filter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))") do

For /f b=%%x do dsmod user %%x -disabled yes >>Disabled users.csv
```

- The first `For` scans the inactive users and puts them in variable `b`.
- The second `For` scans all the users that are not disabled.
- The third `For` compares the inactive users (`b`) with the non disabled (`%%x`) and then disables them and then writes down to a csv file *only the newly added users*.

However this does not work at all.

I am unable to maintain the integrity of the `%%a` values into `b`. It will only set into b the last line of the output.

I've tried using the expression `Tokens=*` etc. - nothing works.

Comment: This is almost ideal for PowerShell because the filter expressions can be fairly complex, so that you can look _specifically_ for users who are (a) _not_ disabled AND (b) have been inactive for the past 90 days.

Comment: You have a mixture of quotes and smart quotes.  Don't use smart quotes. This is not a valid command: `For /f b=%%x`

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I understand from your code is that the number is adding to the environment to stay in the same loop, correct?
I don't know what those commands are, probably from databases, so maybe that's the problem. What you can do is try to correct the syntax, reconfigure the database settings or set a global variant to jump a certain amount of times, based on the users quantity.

The mistake I realized you must be doing all this is that you keep the `>>c:\DisabledLogs\disabledusers.txt` AFTER the FOR command, which may be causing it to show everyone.

However, you can set some jump commands.
Something like:

```
...
set /p jump=<jump.txt
if "%jump%" equ "" set jump=0
:loop
if %jump% equ 0 dsmod user %%a -disabled yes>>c:\DisabledLogs\disabledusers.txt
if %jump% neq 0 set /a jump=%jump%-1 & goto loop.
```

It is a pseudocode, try to adjust this to your need, and try to use the tip I passed on >>.

***Hope this helps,

K.***